# How to use jquery to go to the next page or window in my Electron app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, electron

I'm trying to create a login system. I want the system to take me to another page "page3.htm" when I press the login button. I have been trying to test my system in jquery, but the code below does not seem to work. Why is that?

The "login.js" file contains:

```
window.onload =function() {
    var loginBtn = document.getElementById('go');

    loginBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
        document.location.href = './page3.html';
    });    
}
```

The "index.html" file contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Insert this line above script imports  -->
    <script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>

    <!--Jquery -->
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./jquery-3.3.1.min.js');</script>
    <!--Jquery end  -->
    <!--login css  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/css/login.css">
    <!--login css ends here  -->

    <!--Database link  -->
    <script src='dbcon.js'></script>
    <!--database link ends -->
    <!--login  link  -->
    <script src='login.js'></script>
    <!--login link ends -->

    <style>    
    </style>
  </head>
<body>

<form>
  <h1>Fashion World</h1>
  <div class="inset">
    <p>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="password">PASSWORD</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">
      <label for="remember">Remember me for 14 days</label>
    </p>
  </div>
  <p class="p-container">
    <span>Forgot password ?</span>
    <input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Log in">
  </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you'll need to specify what doesn't work means exactly

Comment: The button when I click it it does not take me to the second window